# What is the best practice in Angular for subscribing to events coming from an Iframe?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, event-handling, dom-events

I have an application written in Angular.
One of my components contains an Iframe. Within the Iframe, there is a (non-angular) application that sends javascript events.
In my component, I would like to subscribe to these events, but not sure, what is the best way to do.
If I were in native Javascript, I would do the following:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create an observable for that

```
  let iFrameEvents = Observable.create((observer) => {
   let eventSource = // create event source here;
   eventSource.onEvent = (event) => observer.next(event.data); // send the new data
  });
```

and you can subscribe to this observable to get your data

Answer (score 1):

Use the `window.addEventListener` as any async call to a server for instance.
In essence - create a service `iframeCommunicator` (you can choose any name you'd like) and inside use this code. Wrap it in an event emitter (or any observable you'd like) and then just inject the service to your component and use it like you'd use socket or http.